# How can I transfer Skype conversations from an old user profile to the new one?

Tags: users, skype

I had to create a new user profile on my Ubuntu 14.04 (Xubuntu) because I was getting so many errors in the original one it was impossible for me to work.

Since I work with Skype every day, I need to transfer the stored Skype conversations from the old user profile to the new one, but I don't know how to do that or even where I can find them.

I will be very thankful for precise explanations.

Answer (score 0):

In Skype 5.4.0.1, pull down the Tools menu, and select `Export chat history from Skype 4.3`.

Comment: Hello heynnema,

thank you for your answer.

I'm still using Skype 4.3.

Comment: Skype 4.3 stopped working on July 1, 2017 and is no longer supported.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Is this why my old conversations aren't transfered automatically? Or is there still a chance?

Comment: Install the new Skype and see if my answer will get you access to your old chats. If that works, you can uninstall Skype 4.3.

Comment: I did. There is only the chat history from july 2017. Is there a chance to get the whole one from Oct. 2016 - july 2017?

Comment: Maybe the errors that you were seeing before affected the chat history log? I don't know for sure. You can probably find old chats in the ~/.Skype folder, but you probably need SQLite to read them. You might check the Skype community support forums for more help.